# AWS s3 image access through REST API

Tags: amazon-s3

I am looking for a solution on the best practice that needs to be followed in AWS S3 access by third party who do not have account in S3.

In my case there are REST interface which would need to provide the link of images .This images resides on AWS S3. Based on the identity of the caller is there a way we can give access to the user. I would not want to make the access level of the bucket to public.

Say if we get a call from user X ( may be we ask them to set a new header ) we allow them the access to the bucket.

As this API is enterprise and we have partners using this API we would want only some of the identified callers to have access to the images.

Any pointers will help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Signed S3 URL's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), make the bucket private, only accessible to your API via an [IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), if the API is running on EC2, lambda etc.

Your API would do the authentication and authorization, then provide the caller a signed s3 url to download the image.

When you create a pre-signed URL for your object, you must provide your security credentials, specify a bucket name, an object key, specify the HTTP method (GET to download the object) and expiration date and time. The pre-signed URLs are valid only for the specified duration.

> Anyone who receives the pre-signed URL can then access the object. For
>   example, if you have a video in your bucket and both the bucket and
>   the object are private, you can share the video with others by
>   generating a pre-signed URL.